# Jinja2 vs. Smarty

Tags: php, python, smarty, jinja2

I always thought that jinja was better because of template extending.. but them I've found this:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl

Is there's any difference of smarty extendings and jinja2 extendings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Smarty is an overkill, in my opinion. I prefer Twig:

http://www.twig-project.org/

You should give it a try if you're stuck with php. It's almost the same as jinja2.

Comment: well, it was my personal saviour 3 months ago when we had to quickly rewrite an app. and the designer jumped right on it!

Comment: I too really like the twig syntax, but while implementing it for a CMS I was developing I found it to be buggy. Twig kept running into issues using associative arrays in the templates. On top of that, it used `eval()`, which was a big red flag for me. I'm not sure if these issues still exist, but if they do, then stay clear! [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) may be a good alternative to Twig and Smarty, although I've not yet tried it.

Comment: The question is tagged both php and python (and django) so I'm not sure if twig is the best answer, generally speaking, even if it seems to be for the OP.